# Force localization of the allowedUnits in DateComponentsFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, date-formatting

I have an app with only one language. I would like to force the language to be this when displaying a time interval since a date. E.g. "9 mths ago" Just in a specific language not english. Is there a way to do this using DateComponentsFormatter which otherwise does exactly what I want to do with the units.

```
    func format(duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(["da"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .short
        formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1

        return formatter.string(from: -duration)!
    }

    format(duration: self.createdDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
```

This returns e.g. "1 yr" when language is en.
I would like to have it in a specific language ("yr" -> "år") this should be similarly done for the other allowed units.

It works when the phone is set to the language of the app.

I tried to set the language before creating the DateComponentsFormatter but it still returned in the language the phone is set to.

**EDIT inserted working code below**

Working code after modification from answer:

```
    func format(duration: TimeInterval) -> String {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "da")
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = calendar
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .short
        formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1

        return formatter.string(from: -duration)!
    }

    format(duration: self.createdDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
```

Comment: First of all, changing `"AppleLanguages"` is not private API, but not documented. Sometimes it works after application restart only in my experience.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's default iOS behavior. If you change your locale and language on phone, you'll notice that is possible to have 2 languages in Calendar application. Sometimes it's possible to change locale, but `includesApproximationPhrase` in your example will not be translated:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "da")
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.calendar = calendar
```

Comment: Setting the fixed calendar of the DateComponentsFormatter worked.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the approximation phrase is NOT localized, what a shame